# QuantLib - Synthetic deposit/FRA rates in yield curve

Tags: python, quantlib, curve-fitting

In my flat forwards dollar curve implemented in QuantLib I would like to add the following instrument:

Today is 12/28/2018
Pillar quote is 1% p.a. (ACT/360)
Pillar start is 1/30/2019 (specific calendar date)
Pillar end is  3/20/2019 (specific calendar date)
Instrument is a flat forward rate

I do not see a helper that I can use to implement this without making wrapper code. Am I missing something?

Here is a paper talking about these kinds of instruments:

https://www.politesi.polimi.it/bitstream/10589/97341/1/2014_10_Mazzocchi.pdf

Math note, these dates overlap with futures implied rates, I would expect the calibration to account for this as per the paper.

Comment: @Luigi Ballabio could you answer this?